# Configuring Twilio SMS from Azure Functions v2

Tags: azure, twilio, azure-functions, sendgrid

I have some code where I'm reading messages off of an Azure Event Hub that I want to either send an email or send an SMS.

The email is working through send grid, but I'm not sure how to configure the SMS part though.

I think I'd want to use Twilio and here's a sample of what my code's like. The "messageCollector" works for sending Email since there's some configuration for SendGrid in the local json. How do I configure Twilio?

```
    [FunctionName("SendAlert")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [EventHubTrigger("v1-email-hub", Connection = "EventHubConnection")] EventData[] events,
        [SendGrid] IAsyncCollector<SendGridMessage> messageCollector,
        [TwilioSms] IAsyncCollector<CreateMessageOptions> smsCollector,
        [Inject] NotificationEventLogic eventLogic,
        ILogger log)
    {

        foreach (EventData eventData in events)
        {

            string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);

            var notificationEvents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NotificationEvent>>(messageBody);

            foreach (var ev in notificationEvents)
            {



                if (ev.NotificationEventType == NotificationEventType.Email)
                {
                    var message = new SendGridMessage();

                    // ... ... make message and add it
                    await messageCollector.AddAsync(message);
                }
                else if (ev.NotificationEventType == NotificationEventType.SMS)
                {
                    // Not sure how to get this to work
                    var mobileMessage = new CreateMessageOptions(new PhoneNumber(ev.Data))
                    {
                        Body = $"Notification {ev.NotificationId}"
                    };

                    await smsCollector.AddAsync(mobileMessage);
                }


                // await smsCollector.AddAsync()
                await eventLogic.CreateEventAsync(ev);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to configure it in attribute

```
[TwilioSms(AccountSidSetting = "TwilioAccountSid", AuthTokenSetting = "TwilioAuthToken", From = "+1425XXXXXXX")]
```

as it mentioned in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-twilio#configuration)

> **TwilioAccountSid**  This value must be set
> to the name of an app setting that holds your Twilio Account Sid e.g.
> TwilioAccountSid. If not set, the default app setting name is
> "AzureWebJobsTwilioAccountSid".
>
> **TwilioAuthToken**   This value must be set to
> the name of an app setting that holds your Twilio authentication token
> e.g. TwilioAccountAuthToken. If not set, the default app setting name
> is "AzureWebJobsTwilioAuthToken".